# Start a new row in a theme based on Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.2.4.

Theme is NewsMag Lite (https://www.machothemes.com/item/newsmag-lite/).

There is a NewsMag Pro that allows a spwcial banner ad widgets.

The theme is based on Bootstrap.

Content area has 3 columns. I place two one-column widgets. Then the third column is free.

Then I occupy 2 columns by vertical one-column widgets. And then again the third dolumn is free.

Well, two columns occupied. I need to announce a new row . Then two more columns to occupy.

Well, I organized an HTML widget  and place it where it belongs. Reload the page - nothing.

Then I reload the admin page - my html widget has disappeared from the Content area.

Questions:
1. Can the theme control what widgets are placed in the content area? I mean maybe they think that any widget can place ads in the theme. That is why they prevent users from insertyng any arbitrary widgets so that people should buy the Pro version.
2. If possible, could you tell me how to start a new row in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a developer, then you should look for the theme template code where the widgets are being listed, and if there is limitation on listing the widgets, simply remove it.

You can also contact the author of the theme and ask if that is possible in the free version (or maybe check the documentation of the theme).

Regards!